# if URI is directory, return 403 forbidden in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my htaccess file, i want to respond with a http 403 code if users attempt to access a directory, however if they attempt to access a file, allow. How is this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn off the [Indexes option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options). Directory listing pages will only be supplied if it is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Using mod_rewrite:

Enable mod_rewrite

If filesystem path matching request (`REQUEST_FILENAME`) is a  directory (`-d`)

Send a 403 header (Forbidden - `[F]`)

(Not sure what exactly to put as first two parameters to RewriteRule, so redirecting anything to root)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule .* / [F]
```